# ASP.NET Core - Syncfusion Chart - donut chart -> how to move the title / how to write the centerlabel

Tags: charts, syncfusion

I'm using asp.net core in VisualStudio 2022 / 6.0
and also using syncfusion in vs - Syncfusion.EJ2.AspNet.Core 21.1.35

and my problem

1. I'm trying to move the title of the chart
2. I want to put the center label into a donut

this is my code.

```
<ejs-dashboardlayout id="dsGm" columns="7" cellSpacing="modelValue.cellSpacing" allowDragging="false">
            <e-dashboardlayout-panels>
                <e-dashboardlayout-panel id="Panel_Platform" sizeX="6" sizeY="2" row="0" col="0">
                    <e-content-template>
                        <div>
                            <div class="e-panel-container">
                                <div class="e-panel-header pt-1">
                                    <div class="fs-3 fw-bolder">
                                        Platform
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="e-panel-content p-2">
                                    <div class="content d-flex justify-content-center">
                                        @{
                                            List<string> _platform = new List<string>() { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE" };

                                            foreach (string platform in _platform)
                                            {
                                                <div class="">
                                                    <ejs-accumulationchart id="chart_@platform" title="@platform" height="380" width="280">
                                                        <e-accumulationchart-margin left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"></e-accumulationchart-margin>
                                                        <e-accumulationchart-centerlabel text="NAME<br>OF<br>PLATFORM"></e-accumulationchart-centerlabel>
                                                        <e-accumulationchart-legendsettings visible="false" position="Top">
                                                        </e-accumulationchart-legendsettings>
                                                        <e-accumulationchart-tooltipsettings enable="false"></e-accumulationchart-tooltipsettings>
                                                        <e-accumulation-series-collection>
                                                            <e-accumulation-series dataSource="ViewBag.dataSource_platform" xName="xValue" yName="yValue" radius="95%" innerRadius="45%" name="Project" explode=true explodeOffset="10%" explodeIndex=3 >
                                                                <e-accumulationseries-datalabel visible="true" name="text">
                                                                    <e-font fontWeight="600" Size="20" color="white"></e-font>
                                                                </e-accumulationseries-datalabel>
                                                            </e-accumulation-series>
                                                        </e-accumulation-series-collection>
                                                    </ejs-accumulationchart>
                                                </div>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </e-content-template>
                </e-dashboardlayout-panel>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1WoA.png)
this is my chart

I want to move this title to bottom like this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbtSn.png)

and I want to put the center label into a donut
like this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VRAC.png)

this is my another chart. and this chart can show the center label
but my five chart is can't...

please help me T.T

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

Please find the below response for your queries.

***Query 1: I'm trying to move the title of the chart.***

We do not have support to change the title of the chart. Instead, we can add the title based on your requirements by using the annotations in the chart. The annotation can be placed anywhere in the chart by using the x and y properties in the annotations. Please find the below code snippet for your reference.

Code Snippet:

```xml
<e-accumulationchart-accumulationannotations>
<e-accumulationchart-accumulationannotation Content="<div style='font-size: 15px;font-weight: 500;'>AAA</div>" X="50%" Y="95%" CoordinateUnits='@Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.Units.Pixel' region='@Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.Regions.Chart'></e-accumulationchart-accumulationannotation>
</e-accumulationchart-accumulationannotations>
```

Please find the below UG link for your reference.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/accumulation-chart/annotation

***Query 2: I need to set the center label in the donut.***

We can add the center label to the pie chart by using the text property in the `centerlabel` of the chart. When we hover on the slice in the pie chart, then the center label will be rendered based on the information of the center label. Please find the below code snippet for your reference.

Code Snippet:

```xml
<e-accumulationchart-centerlabel text="Mobile<br>Browsers<br>Statistics" hoverTextFormat="${point.x}<br>Browser Share<br>${point.y}%">
</e-accumulationchart-centerlabel>
```

We have created a core application for the above two queries, which can be downloaded from the attached sample.